# CVS add file to the repository

Tags: cvs

I have added a new file using command:

```
cvs add test1.php
```

But I have not commit it and rename the file `test1.php` to `test2.php`.

Then cvs add it:   `cvs add test2.php`.

When I commit does the file with the name test1.php will be added to the repository and if yes, then how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it before commiting.

```
cvs remove test1.php
```